# Mixed conditional and sequence of events

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, conditional-perfect

I want to express the opinion that if a man somehow travelled in time from 2006 to 2016 he would find a lot of new stuff. I remember an episode of South Park called "[Prehistoric Ice Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_Ice_Man)" and want to refer to it, by using "prehistoric" word to emphasize the large difference between now and 10 years ago, so I built the following sentence:

> If a prehistoric man had been frozen in 2006 and then thawed out
>   in 2016, he would discover the whole new world.

Questions:

- Does "thawed out" use the proper tense in that sentence? It's part of the condition, but on the other hand it happens after the initial condition(frozen first, thawed out then), so I am not really sure.
- Can I replace "If" with "Should", like "Should a prehistoric man..."

Comment: -1 because you fail to justify/explain the use of 'would discover', where we would expect 'would have discovered'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tense for *thawed out* is okay.

I do not recommend replacing *if* with *should*.  It sounds show-off-y to me.  Better to stick with something straightforward and clear.